# 'betrayal' of expectations

Tags: word-choice

I read a line in my textbook that goes:

> Negative effects may arise due to a 'betrayal' of expectations when people involved fail to understand the situational context.

Can the word 'betrayal' and 'expectations' be used together? Does it seem awkward when viewed by a native speaker?

Comment: why not? https://www.google.com/search?q=%22betrayal%20of%20expectations%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en

Comment: Can you tell us why you think they don't work together?

Comment: No particular reason, it's just my personal thought (which is now proven wrong). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

"betray" in this context has the following meaning:

> betray — go against promise: to act in a way that is contrary to a promise made

The "expectations" are taking the place of "promise" in the definition and so the phrase "betrayal of expectations" would mean something akin to "acting in way we did not expect" or "acting against expectations."

Your example sentence as a whole sounds a little strange to me but the phrase "betrayal of expectations" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: PS) If I were to reword your example sentence slightly I would do something like, "When people involved fail to understand the situational context, negative effects may arise due to a betrayal of their expectations."

Answer (score 0):

"betrayal" can mean deception. But I think the common word is "deception". As "betrayal" normally means giving away a secret, I think, the word is losing out to "deception". 
With "betrayal of expectations" the author wants to say that your expectations don't come true.